# Separate and group all objects into a new array based on a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, grouping

I have an array of objects which I need to split into 2 arrays, one which has all the objects matching a particular property and the other array with the rest of the objects.

For e.g., here's a sample array:

```
const fruits = [
    {name:"orange", qty: 1},
    {name:"orange", qty: 2},
    {name:"banana", qty: 4},
    {name:"apple", qty: 6},
    {name:"kiwi", qty: 3},
    {name:"apple", qty: 2}
];
```

What I need to do is group all the objects together with the name `apple` in one array and the rest into another.

Expected:

```
const fruits1 = [
    {name:"orange", qty: 1},
    {name:"orange", qty: 2},
    {name:"banana", qty: 4},
    {name:"kiwi", qty: 3},
];


const fruits2 = [
    {name:"apple", qty: 6},
    {name:"apple", qty: 2}
];
```

I could do this using filter, but then I've to loop over fruits twice. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: "_using filter, ... I've loop over fruits twice_"? How is that? Could you show your filter loop?

Comment: Use a simple loop. If the name is "apple",  add it to `fruits2` array else `fruits1` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `partition` function that separates items to two arrays according to a predicate. Use `Array.reduce()` to iterate the array, and apply the predicate to each item. The predicate should return a boolean. Casting the boolean result to number will give us 0 for `false`, and 1 for `true`. Use the number as the index of the sub-array to push the item to. You can assign the results to `fruit1` and `fruit2` using destructuring.

```js
const partition = (predicate, arr) => arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[+predicate(o)].push(o);
  
  return r;
}, [[], []]);

const fruits = [{"name":"orange","qty":1},{"name":"orange","qty":2},{"name":"banana","qty":4},{"name":"apple","qty":6},{"name":"kiwi","qty":3},{"name":"apple","qty":2}];

const [fruits1, fruits2] = partition(o => o.name === 'apple', fruits);

console.log(fruits1);
console.log(fruits2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's less functional, but you can `push` to one or another array, depending on the `name`:

```js
const fruits = [
    {name:"orange", qty: 1},
    {name:"orange", qty: 2},
    {name:"banana", qty: 4},
    {name:"apple", qty: 6},
    {name:"kiwi", qty: 3},
    {name:"apple", qty: 2}
];

const apples = [];
const others = [];
for (const fruit of fruits) {
  (fruit.name === 'apple' ? apples : others).push(fruit);
}
console.log(apples);
```

If you have to use an array method without mutating outside variables, you can use `reduce` to combine into two arrays at once, but it doesn't look so readable:

```js
const fruits = [
    {name:"orange", qty: 1},
    {name:"orange", qty: 2},
    {name:"banana", qty: 4},
    {name:"apple", qty: 6},
    {name:"kiwi", qty: 3},
    {name:"apple", qty: 2}
];

const [apples, others] = fruits.reduce((a, fruit) => {
  (fruit.name === 'apple' ? a[0] : a[1]).push(fruit);
  return a;
}, [[], []]);
console.log(apples);
console.log(others);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach()`. You can even use `filter()` array function but for that you need to use that `filter()` twice. So, minimise your complexity using a single loop:

```js
const fruits = [
    {name:"orange", qty: 1},
    {name:"orange", qty: 2},
    {name:"banana", qty: 4},
    {name:"apple", qty: 6},
    {name:"kiwi", qty: 3},
    {name:"apple", qty: 2}
];

let fruits1 = [];
let fruits2 = [];

fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
  if(fruit.name === 'apple') {
    fruits2.push(fruit);
  } else {
    fruits1.push(fruit);
  }
});

console.log('fruits1', fruits1);
console.log('fruits2', fruits2);
```